# For-loop takes long time to create views in iOS

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiview

I have a for loop in my code that fetches data from a JSON file and create many UIViews as the number of the users found.

```
for (index, element) in 0...countUser {
  .... // create views
}
```

I have more than 200 views to be create and the process takes long time to be shown.

Is there a way to create the views and show them 1 by 1 while the other are created in the for loop?

Or is there a way to load the first 10 and when scroll to the 10th view next 10 are created ?

Comment: Creating 200 views is almost always a bad idea in any case, particularly on iOS. Almost certainly the tool you want here is a `UICollectionView` which will request views from you as they are needed for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `UICollectionView` instead of creating your views manually. The collection view cells will be more efficient. Also you will have advantages when you want to access a specific index. Read Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/).